# Getting snakes to work (latex+tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf

A Latex+tikz question for you: I can't seem to get snakes to work (scientific linux 6.3).  I've been looking at the tikz manual; sure would like to know how to get those snakes!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
  % p43 : can't get snakes to work
  %       \usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,backgrounds}      \draw [->,snakes=snake] (0,0) -- (2,0)      : Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/snakes' and I am going to...
  %       \usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,backgrounds}      \draw [->,snake=snake] (0,0) -- (2,0)       : Package tikz Warning: Snakes have been superseded by decorations. Please use th...
  %       \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations,backgrounds} \draw [->,snake=snake] (0,0) -- (2,0)       : I can't find file `tikzlibrarydecoration.code.tex'...
  %       \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations,backgrounds} \draw [->,decoration=snake] (0,0) -- (2,0)  : Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/snake' and I am...
  %       \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations,backgrounds} \draw [->,decoration=snakes] (0,0) -- (2,0) : Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/snakes' and I a
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [->,decoration=snake] (0,0) -- (2,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to load the right `decorations` library, not just the general one. In this case, `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}` will get your example to compile, and adding `decorate` to your `\draw` option will actually make the snake show up.

Comment: I'm almost there...    \draw [->,decorate,decoration=snake,line after snake=1mm] (0,0) -- (2,0);    doesn't recognize the "line after snake=1mm" as given in the tikz manual.  Presumably the command has changed?

Comment: Yes, it has. You now have to use `decoration={snake, post length=1mm}`.

Comment: @Jake fancy posting an answer? Or else vote to close as TL?

Comment: how to install latex in scientifc linux 6.3

Comment: @user21497 Advice: Always read the documentation for the version of the package that you are using! Try this command: `texdoc tikz`.

Comment: @user24128 I converted your non-answer to a comment. I think it should be removed later. If you have a new question, please post a new question.